# I am using EF, Prism, Wpf and have trouble with RaiseCanExecute(), as well as I need help what to do with pure POCO classes

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, prism, poco

I am building an app in Wpf with EF and Prism. I got to a point when I am confused about staff, let me explain. Please note this is a very simplified version.
I have my POCO classes which look like this

```
public class SaleText
{
    public int SaleTextId { get; set; }
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SaleDepartment SaleDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Now my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SaleTextViewModel
{
    private SaleText selectedSaleText;
    public SaleText SelectedSaleText
    {
        get { return selectedSaleText; }
        set
        {
            selectedSaleText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now my xaml looks like this

```
    <Label Content="Information" />
    <TextBox Width="200"
             Height="100"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             Text="{Binding SelectedSaleText.Description }"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
     <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save" />
```

The save button is only enabled when description was typed in.

```
 private bool CanSave()
 {
    if (SelectedEntity.Description)
    {
          return true;
    }
    else
    {
          return false;
    }
 }
```

And now the problems start I am never notified when the description is changed because that property does not have On property changed. So I thought, I just expand it to fully implemented property like this .

```
    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Looks great and the setter is called every time something has changed. But the real difficulties start here, I am using prism 5 delegate command like this

```
    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    protected FormViewModelBase(IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base(regionManager)
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);
    }


    protected override bool CanSave()
    {
       if (SelectedEntity.Description)
       {
            return true;
       }
       else
       {
            return false;
       }
    }

    protected override void Save()
    {
          // then other code deals with saving changes            

    EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateSaleDepartmentSaleTextEvent>()
    .Publish(SelectedEntity);

     }
```

But the button never gets updated, that its ok to save now, because it obviously needs this

```
     SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); inside here  where the space is.

    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

But I cannot do it, because the entities are in a different project, and my wpf project is referencing the entities project not the other way around.

Can anyone tell me what do I do in this situation ? Do I leave my POCO as it was at the beginning with just properties, and then create another set of entities, which will then deal with INPC RaiseCanExecute, Validations etc? if so, how do I translate between the two?

Any ideas please?

**EDIT:** Here is a possible solution

```
public class FooSaleText : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int SaleTextId { get; set; }
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }

    readonly DelegateCommand command;

    public FooSaleText(DelegateCommand command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }

    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string importText;
    public string ImportText
    {
        get { return importText; }
        set
        {
            importText = value;
            command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SaleDepartment SaleDepartment { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}



public class SaleTextConversion
{
    readonly DelegateCommand command;

    public SaleTextConversion(DelegateCommand command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public FooSaleText Convert(SaleText saleText)
    {
        return new FooSaleText(command)
        {
            SaleTextId = saleText.SaleTextId,
            SaleDepartmentId = saleText.SaleDepartmentId,
            SaleDepartment = saleText.SaleDepartment,
            Description = saleText.Description,
        };
    }

    public SaleText ConvertBack(FooSaleText saleText)
    {
        return new SaleText()
        {
            SaleTextId = saleText.SaleTextId,
            SaleDepartmentId = saleText.SaleDepartmentId,
            SaleDepartment = saleText.SaleDepartment,
            Description = saleText.Description,                
        };
    }
```

Here is the viemodel change

```
 public class SaleTextViewModel
 {
       private FooSaleText selectedSaleText;
       public FooSaleText SelectedSaleText
       {
          get { return selectedSaleText; }
          set
       {
          selectedSaleText = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
       }
 public void TestMethod()
 {
    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWorkMAOption())
    {
        var foo = new SaleTextConversion(SaveCommand);
        SelectedSaleText =
        foo.Convert(unitOfWork.SaleTextRepository.Find(Id);
    }
 }
```

And the POCO is not modified at all. If somebody has a different or better solution please share it with me :)

Comment: Yes, leave as your POCO was in the beginning. Create new viemwmodels for each POCO and then your problem is solved, and it looks nice. You can translate by writing conversion routines that can translate from viewmodels to models for your repository, alternatively use automapper.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Hi, thanks for the answer. Would you be able to provide a small chunk of code how to create that conversion routine. Because the only way I know is to make each property from a poco class = property from viewmodel. But that seems like alot of work, and I am not quite sure whether its a proper approach. Some code how to deal with it would be appreciated. Ps I'll look at the automapper later when I have a proper understanding of how everything works, but now I'd love to be able to solve it without any additional frameworks.

Comment: Yes, "each property from a poco class = property from viewmodel" is the approach I use. It works nicely in real life scenarios, and it's very flexible, doesn't pollute model. I alternatively added an answer that can help you with your current case.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa hi, I've created that copy of my POCO, and then I've added all the things I wanted to add to it for the moment, and it seems to work (please see the Edit of my post). I tried the code you pasted in your answer, but the sender is always a class which derives from my FormViewModelBase (not the property my view is bound to), so it did not quite work for me. I leave the post open for a couple of days, see if everybody else comes with another solution, to compare it. If not then I just accept your answer and get on with it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   protected FormViewModelBase(IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base(regionManager)
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);
        PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => {
        if(sender == SelectedSaleText &&
            args.PropertyName == "Description")
                SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();   
        };
    }
```

You can always listen to the property changes in `SelectedSaleText`.